# Space with custom, discrete axes

Tags: graphics3d

The 2D lattice might be something like this:

\begin{array}{cccc}
D&(E,D)&(F,D)&(G,D)\\
C&(E,C)&(F,C)&(G,C)\\
B&(E,B)&(F,B)&(G,B)\\
0&E&F&G
\end{array}

Is it possible to graph these custom axes in a 2D lattice, or even a 3D lattice with 3 custom axes, and also show the coordinates for each point in the space?

Comment: I don't find this question clearly posed. It looks like you have a 2D lattice. Is that correct? If so, then I don't see how a 3D graphic can be generated. A 2D graphic. can be generated easily from a numeric table (matrix) of the points. Custom labelling is certainly possible. That'a about all i can say without seeing your real data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
xs = {"E", "F", "G"};
ys = {"B", "C", "D"};

converter = {Thread[xs -> Range[Length[xs]]], Thread[ys -> Range[Length[ys]]]}
 (* {{"E" -> 1, "F" -> 2, "G" -> 3}, {"B" -> 1, "C" -> 2, "D" -> 3}} *)

pts = {{"E", "D"}, {"E", "C"}, {"E", "B"}, {"F", "D"}, {"F", 
    "C"}, {"F", "B"}, {"G", "D"}, {"G", "C"}, {"G", "B"}};

ListPlot[
 Callout[#[[1]], ToString[#[[2]]]] & /@ Transpose[{pts /. Flatten[converter], pts}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, Length[xs] + .5}, {0, Length[ys] + .5}}, 
 Ticks -> {{#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ Reverse[converter[[1]], 2], 
           {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ Reverse[converter[[2]], 2]}]
```

[image]

In 3 dimensions:

```
(* Some z "values" *)
zs = {"H", "I", "J"};
converter = {Thread[xs -> Range[Length[xs]]], 
  Thread[ys -> Range[Length[ys]]], Thread[zs -> Range[Length[zs]]]}
 (* {{"E" -> 1, "F" -> 2, "G" -> 3}, {"B" -> 1, "C" -> 2, "D" -> 3}, {"H" -> 1, "I" -> 2, "J" -> 3}} *)
```

Making up some 3D points (just a few, not the full lattice):

```
pts = {{"E", "D", "H"}, {"E", "C", "I"}, {"E", "B", "J"}, {"F", "D", 
    "J"}, {"F", "C", "H"}, {"F", "B", "I"}, {"G", "D", "I"}, {"G", 
    "C", "I"}, {"G", "B", "I"}};

ListPointPlot3D[
 Callout[#[[1]], ToString[#[[2]]]] & /@ Transpose[{pts /. Flatten[converter], pts}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, Length[xs] + .5}, {0, Length[ys] + .5}, {0, Length[zs] + .5}}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Ticks -> {{#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ Reverse[converter[[1]], 2], 
           {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ Reverse[converter[[2]], 2], 
           {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ Reverse[converter[[3]], 2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what i'm looking for

Comment: Is this possible for 3D ?

Comment: @Manx see update